# Bidirectional one-to-one mapped to multiple fields

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a domain class called `Flight` that represents a flight that has been flown. I have another class called `Movement` which can represents either a departure or an arrival and contains a date and time and the airport at which the movement occured.

```
@Entity
public class Flight implements Serializable {

    private Movement departure;
    private Movement arrival;
}

@Entity
public class Movement implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateTime;
    @ManyToOne
    private Airport airport;

    private Flight flight;
}
```

I am however not sure how to properly annotate the `flight` field in the `Movement` class. I figured the `Flight` class has to be the owning side of the relationship because if it is not, there is no way to tell if the `Movement` of a specific `Flight` was the `departure` or the `arrival`:

```
@OneToOne
private Movement departure;
@OneToOne
private Movement arrival;
```

This, however, poses a problem. I can't map the `flight` field in the `Movement` class on both fields:

```
// This obviously does not work
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "departure")
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "arrival")
private Flight flight;
```

How would I go about properly annotating this, having both the `departure` and `arrival` field properly reference the `Movement` and still be able to have the `flight` field on the `Movement` class reference the `Flight` class?

Comment: Why do the movements need to know what flight they're in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need a bidirectional relationship, then you'll need to have to fields in movement, with one of them always being null:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "departure")
private Flight departureFlight;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "arrival")
private Flight arrivalFlight;
```

But you could have a single getter:

```
public Flight getFlight() {
    return departureFlight == null ? arrivalFlight : departureFlight;
}
```

Comment: One should not forget that "regular" getters should still be implemented for JPA tool to use.

Comment: @MaDa: no. JPA can directly get/set values from/to the fields, without the need for getters/setters.

Comment: Are you quite sure ANY JPA tool could do it? I doubt if this is a part of the spec... Laurens does not say what he uses.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. See paragraph 2.1.1 of the spec: "The persistent state of an entity is accessed by the persistence provider runtime either via JavaBeans style property accessors or via instance variables". JPA2 even introduced the @Access annotation allowing to specify which access type to use, and mixing access types inside a single entity

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone! Considering everyone's input I have decided to change the relationship to a unidirectional one and avoid the problem altogether. Thinking it over made me realize I did not absolutely need the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you need two way relationship, you could change relation type to `@ManyToMany`, so you could use a join table with additional status column. There you'd specify whether it's an arrival or departure.

[Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany) provide an example how to map it. This kind of relation, though, is quite cumbersome to handle in code.

Or maybe you don't need a two way relationship at all, as glowcoder suggests? It would be much simpler to map, use, and faster to run.